# msal - personal and work accounts with same email address

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We are inviting externals as guest to azure AD by email address. Now some of them have a personal AND a work account with this email address.
If they link the personal account with our tenant and try to connect with python MSAL library, they will get an error.

- If they use their work account password, they will get: 'error':
  'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'AADSTS50020: User account
  '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider
  'https://sts.windows.net/xxx-xx-xx/' does not exist in tenant
  'Contoso' and cannot access the application 'xxx-xx-xx-xx'(Contoso
  App) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external
  user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different
  Azure Active Directory user account.'
- If they use their personal account password, they will get: 'error':
  'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'AADSTS50126: Error validating
  credentials due to invalid username or password.'

I think, msal is resolving the user email address as work account and try to login that one (which will fail) - and not the personal one which shall have the permissions to use the app.

Is there any way to fix this programmatically? We are currently using a ROPC flow for that; and I know, this is not the recommended way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. What you have added into your tenant is personal account rather than work account. You get the first error because MSAL is trying to recognize your user as work account. But the user is in fact a work account from other tenant. So it requires you add it (work account) as guest into this tenant.

But per my understanding, you are trying to user ROPC flow for guest users(personal account added into your tenant) right?

Unfortunately, it's not supported. See the **Important** tip in [ROPC flow document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). It is why you get the second error.

[image]

So what you want can not be implemented.

If you have to use ROPC flow, the only way is adding work account as guest into your tenant and assign the permissions to them to use the app.